# Convert Order Address into customer Address

Tags: shipping-address, customer-address, billing-address

Under a sales_order_place_after event Observer, I try I save a guest customer and I try to save the order Adresses into the guest customer Adresses:

I get the the Billing and Shipping Adresses like this:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();  
$billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress(); 
$shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
```

And I want to save them to the guest customer.

How can I do it ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Please check below link for adding customer:
http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programmaticaly-adding-new-customers-to-the-magento-store/

Comment: Thanks, I have already seen that link, is there any method to save directly  the complete Shipping or BillingAdress in better method that setting each Address attribute alone like in the link ? Thanks

Comment: Hii, we can not set directly you need to assign the values of the field like see the below links:

Comment: Hi, see this link

Comment: http://feltsales-magento.blogspot.in/2012/04/adding-address-programmatically-in.html

Comment: I have already seen this link, it haven't worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Please use this extension for that :
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/quick-register.html